# how to compare multiple id avaialble in antoher string?

Tags: php, compare, logic

below are two string variable.
how to check `$str2` is contain all values of `$str1`?

```
$str1 = ',2,4,13,11,';

$str2 = ',1,2,22,20,6,4,21,18,4.146,11,1.124,13,';
```

i know its possible using loop, but i want to know that is it possible directly or not?

Comment: kindly provide what kind of expected output you are looking for

Comment: i just want to check that $str2 contains all values of $str1 or not?

Comment: convert strings into an array by using explode() and use array_diff() function.

Comment: Do you want to allow `$str1` to have more values than `$str2`, or does the statement go both ways?

Comment: no, i dont want to all more values in $str1, thanks @Manav

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
<?php

$str1 = ',2,4,13,11';

$str2 = ',1,2,22,20,6,4,21,18,4.146,11,1.124,13,';

$arr1 = explode(",",$str1);

$arr2 = explode(",",$str2);

$subArray = count(array_intersect($arr1 , $arr2)) == count($arr1);

if($subArray) {
    echo 'TRUE';
} else {
    echo 'FALSE';
}
?>
```

Comment: Otherwise, as @Alankar said, you can alternately use `array_diff()`

Answer (score 1):

With `array_diff` and `explode` functions:

```
$str1 = ',2,4,13,11,';
$str2 = ',1,2,22,20,6,4,21,18,4.146,11,1.124,13,';

$contains_all = ! array_diff(explode(',', trim($str1,',')), explode(',', trim($str2,',')));
var_dump($contains_all);  // true
```